# Prevent repeated sub-string search in string JAVA

Tags: java, regex

This is what I did:

```
String[] conjunctions = new String[] {
            "after", "although", "as if",
            "as long as", "as much as", "as soon as",
            "as though", "because", "before", "by the time",
            "even if", "even though", "if",

    };
    for (String toSearch : conjunctions) {
        int occurrence = textToAnalyse.split("(?i)\\W" + toSearch +"\\W").length - 1;
        System.out.println(toSearch + " X " + occurrence);
    }
```

for example, `"if"`, and `"even if"` will be considered as the same thing as `"if"` will be counted twice. Is there a way to prioritize the search to the latter, and prevent JAVA from searching it twice? many thanks

input:

```
textToAnalyse = "Even if you are smart, you are still dumb."
```

Expected output:

```
even if X 1
if X 0
```

Comment: please explain your problem properly. add input, output or expected out.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably change your approach somewhat. Consider defining your conjunctions as a list of mutually exclusive regular expressions, then count the number of matches. As a happy side-effect, that approach would also remove the need to construct a large number of substrings, which should help with memory usage.